# Is it safe to drive on my damaged wheel?

Tags: wheels

I recently hit a curb and it damaged my wheel/rim.

Would it be safe to still drive for now?

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, that looks pretty bad. If you're only doing 25 mph to a nearby shop to get it fixed, it'll probably hold and be fine, but I wouldn't recommend driving it on a highway.

Most of the damage appears to have been done to the hub cap, with only minor damage to the steel wheel. However, that damage appears to have warped the rim and impacted the bead, so it might have a wobble or shake if you drove fast, and might wear funny and potentially explode or go flat.

Comment: Steel wheels are incredibly hardy. You smashed the plastic cap, but that's a cosmetic issue. The outer portion of the rim appears to have a slight bend, which is not really a big deal. It might throw off your tire balance, which might make a less comfortable ride, but that's a comfort issue. Some shops might be willing to bend it back a bit, after dismounting the tire, but what are you trying to accomplish with that? I'd run it.

Answer (score 1):

> would it be safe to still drive for now?

NO absolutely not safe.  Do  not drive on it.

There are sharp edges exposed and they can and will cut into the sidewall of the tire sooner or later depending on many factors.

You could limp it into a tire shop if you go slow and be careful.

Comment: I downvoted because this is clearly wrong. It's a slight bend in a steel wheel. Whatever sharp edges you think you see in the picture are not there (they are probably on the plastic cap), and they certainly aren't in contact with the tire.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to see a picture with the hubcap removed, but from what I can see I would only drive to a shop to get a new wheel.  The sidewall is distorted and although it's still holding air the handling and performance of the tire will be affected.  I would be concerned that the bead may separate at some point.
Also, there will most likely be other driveability problems.
Steel wheels are relatively inexpensive.  You should have it replaced.

Comment: Beads don't separate, as in, a "tire separation". You probably mean lose it's seal, leading to a flat.

Comment: BTW, since you've posted this, steel wheels are no longer "relatively inexpensive". They are over $150 now.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the alignment checked with the new wheel and tire. That will also determine if any other work is needed. I did similar damage and needed a lower A frame replaced ( it was aluminum , a steel A frame would be less likely to have damage.)